# Why is the text blurry second instance in Google Chrome on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, gnome3, chrome

I'm running Google Chrome on Debian 9 stable with Gnome 3.22. Just yesterday, Chrome's tab text, page text, and bookmark bar text became blurry when I tried to open another Chrome instances (<kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd>). I tried to change Gnome's default fonts to fix it, but it didn't work. It will go back to normal after I terminate all instances and re-open the browser.

[image: Normal v.s. Blurry]

But when I open new tab (<kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd>) in the first instance of Chrome everything is fine, even I right-click on an URL to open a new tab or window.
Any suggestion to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around this by enabling chrome://flags##lcd-text-aa. I don't understand why. I first *disabled* it, assuming this was a RGB-subpixel rendering issue (xrandr can't determine my monitor's subpixel order, so I guessed it could be that). That didn't help. But *enabling* it seems to have worked, somehow.